# dotnet, use dynamic object to initiate generic type

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamic, reflection

I need to create an Instance of a generic class using dynamic object

Using the following code sample

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.num = 1;
        obj.str = "a";

        Type t = obj.GetType();
        Type myType = typeof(RulesService<>).MakeGenericType(t);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, 999);

        myType.GetMethod("GetMatchingRules")
            .Invoke(instance, obj);
    }
}

public class RulesService<T>
{
    private readonly int _retNum = 0;

    public RulesService(int retNum)
    {
        _retNum = retNum;
    }

    public int GetMatchingRules(T objectToMatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetMatchingRules");
        return _retNum;
    }
}
```

and getting the next exception

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object, object[])' has some invalid arguments
> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , MethodInfo , Object , Object )
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
> at Program.Main()

Comment: Have you tried explicitly creating an `object[]` in `Invoke`? `myType.GetMethod("GetMatchingRules").Invoke(instance, new object[] { obj });`

Comment: Can you please share with us why do you want to create a generic class with a `dynamic`  type parameter? I mean, what is the real use case (not talking about this made up example)?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the object into array:

```cs
myType.GetMethod("GetMatchingRules").Invoke(instance, new[]{ obj });
```

[`MethodBase.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-7.0#system-reflection-methodbase-invoke(system-object-system-object())) requires an array of parameters and will try to treat `obj` as one. The issue will become clear if you try casting the dynamic instance to `ExpandoObject` (`myType.GetMethod("GetMatchingRules).Invoke(instance, (ExpandoObject) obj);`)

P.S.

Note that using `dynamic` is rarely a right choice in C# applications.